# SWRevealViewController nil error

Tags: swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController

When i was click on BackButton getting this error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

> my code

```
let nesne:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()//the error here
let mainStroyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let desController = mainStroyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as! MessageViewController
let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
nesne.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> solution

```
let sw = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

let mainStroyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let desController = mainStroyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as! MessageViewController
let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
sw.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: The above works, but the after the view controller is loaded, the swReveal functionality for the menu sliding out stops working!?